# Single YAML file VS multiple YAML files in different folders and subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, translation, rails-i18n, transifex

I am working on automating the translation workflow and improving the Localization process as a whole of a Rails website. I am using SimpleBackend so only YAML files are used for storing translations.

The current locales directory consists of folders, then sub-folders (in some cases) and those sub-folders containing yml files. I am considering to integrate the project with some third-party tool like Transifex for translation management so may be using a single YAML file for each language may be good for management of workflow.

If someone can highlight the pros and cons of both structures then it would be really helpful to decide whether I should switch from nested file structure to single file pattern or not. Also, the project is an Open-Source project with active contributors and so thinking for a long-term solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think whatever tools you are using to make the process flow smoothly factors a lot in this decision. You should explore how exactly Transifex wants things to be structured in output, and try to keep your current input structure, and give that a shot before making a decision.

However, in my opinion, for a large app with a lot of translatable text, my preference would be to allow for multiple yaml files in your default locale, and one or two consolidated yaml files for each foreign translation. If there isn't a lot of translatable text in your app, maybe a single file is fine for you, but given it's already split up, there's a good chance that's the better choice. On a team with many contributors you can end up with a very high churn file (maybe with a lot of merge conflicts) that everyone changes all the time.

Splitting into separate files lets you logically separate out text to match a domain in your app, like a separate yaml file for mailers (or even each mailer), and one for each domain (or controller). Either way, it puts you in control of your organization strategy.

However, there isn't a lot of value, IMO in separating your foreign translations to mirror that structure. The systems I have experience with (not Transifex) generate your foreign translation files for you, so you just need to sync with the web interface and commit the results.